# Bash read arguments as commands

Tags: bash

I want to do something like this:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --some-switch date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" >> unit-tests-runs.log
```

Everything after bash is basically treated as if I'm in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `-c` Flag

You need [the `-c` flag](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash) and some quotes. For example:

```
$ bash -c 'date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" >> unit-tests-runs.log'
```